# Windows 8 Metro Style App Samples

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting this kind of errors while compiling any of the Win 8 Metro style app samples provided by Microsoft (VS 2012 RC):

> Error 1   Source file 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Windows 8 Release Preview
>   Metro style app samples - C#, VB.NET, C++, JavaScript\XAML images
>   sample\C#\obj\Release\App.g.i.cs' could not be
>   found C:\Users\me\Desktop\Windows 8 Release Preview Metro style app
>   samples - C%23%2c VB.NET%2c C%2b%2b%2c JavaScript\XAML images
>   sample\C#\CSC Images
>
> Error 2   Source file 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\Windows 8 Release Preview
>   Metro style app samples - C#, VB.NET, C++, JavaScript\XAML images
>   sample\C#\obj\Release\App.g.cs' could not be
>   found C:\Users\me\Desktop\Windows 8 Release Preview Metro style app
>   samples - C%23%2c VB.NET%2c C%2b%2b%2c JavaScript\XAML images
>   sample\C#\CSC Images

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's related to the folder name you chose for the samples - I suspect that the # character is causing issues for the various tooling.  You might try using CS instead of C#.

Comment: Huh! This worked :) Thanx. Funny since I adopted the folder name just as downloaded from the MS site.

Answer (score 1):

rename the folder to something simple with shorter length and without special characters.

Answer (score 1):

remove hyphen (-) and other special characters from the folder name.